# Javascript: Iterating over JSON objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON object that I want to iterate through.

```
"phone": {
    "Samsung": {
        "type": "S7"
    },
    "iPhone": {
        "type": "6S"
    },
    "Google": {
        "type": "Pixel"
    }
}
```

I'm using `Object.key` to map through each of these values, which I THINK is the correct way to work with objects:

```
render() {
    //this.props.phone contains the objects "Samsung", "iPhone", and "Google"
    return (
        Object.keys(this.props.phones).map((type) => {
            console.log(type)
            return (
                <p>Type of phone: {type}</p>
            )
        })
    )
}
```

However, the `console.log` above returns this when I was expecting an object to return:

[image]

Why is it returning a value, and not an object?

Comment: *"Return value: An array of strings that represent all the enumerable properties of the given object."* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is strictly speaking a [ecmascript-2017](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2017) answer, but it can easily be shimmed into older versions of Javascript.

You want to use either [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) or [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to loop through all the properties in an object. Where `Object.keys` gives you the keys, `Object.values` gives you the properties (well, duh) and `Object.entries` gives you an array `[key, value]` for each entry in the object.

You don't use the key in your current code, so here's the `Object.values` option:

```
    Object.values(this.props.phones).map((type) => {
        console.log(type)
        return (
            <p>Type of phone: {type}</p>
        )
    })
```

and here's the `Object.entries` option, if you wanted to use both:

```
    Object.entries(this.props.phones).map(([make, type]) => {
        console.log(make)
        console.log(type)
        return (
            <p>Make of phone: {make}</p>
            <p>Type of phone: {type}</p>
        )
    })
```

You'll see that we're using ES6 destructuring to get the two values out of the array we get from `Object.entries`.

The shims are linked on the MDN pages for each function.

Comment: Best answer for explaining different options and making it clear :) thank you!

Comment: Hi, just see your great answer. Just one thing I don't understand in you answers is that how can you return html string without using any quotation marks? and is that {} notation angular? Thanks

Comment: @TypingPanda This is React. (To answer both your questions.)

Comment: If you forget `[ ]` in `map(([make, type])`, you won't receive the desired outcome.

Answer (score 5):

Because you iterate over object keys. To return object in your case you have to use given key to get its value:

```
render() {
    //this.props.phone contains the objects "Samsung", "iPhone", and "Google"
    return (
        Object.keys(this.props.phones).map((type) => {
            console.log(this.props.phones[type])
            ...
        })
    )

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The keys of an object are strings, so that is what you will get back when looking at `Object.keys(someObject)`. The value associated with that key is the object you were looking for. In order to obtain the value, in your map iteration, you would need to access the object with your key.

```
var self = this;//close over this value for use in map
return (
    Object.keys(this.props.phones).map((type) => {
        console.log(self.props.phones[type]);//this will yield the object
        return (
            <p>Type of phone: {self.props.phones[type]}</p>
        )
    })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have iterated over the keys. So the `type` variable in your loop will be set to `Samsung`, `iPhone` and `Google`. Then you use `this.props.phone[type]` to access the value objects. Please fix the `phones` key in your code which is different from `phone` key in the JSON object.

```
render() {
    //this.props.phone contains the objects "Samsung", "iPhone", and "Google"
    return (
        Object.keys(this.props.phone).map((type) => {
            console.log(this.props.phone[type])
            return (
                <p>Type of phone: {this.props.phone[type]}</p>
            )
        })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrow function and destructuring of params to make it easier to read your code. Since `Object.keys` return the keys of the given object as an array, you need to iterate over the array and extract the value using the current `key`. You need to assign a unique key to list elements in React, so `p key={phoneKey}..` is related to that, for more information checkout [Lists and Keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```
const {phones} = this.props;
const phoneKeys = Object.keys(phones);

render() {
    return (
        phoneKeys.map(phoneKey) => <p key={phoneKey}>Type of phone: {phones[phoneKey].type}</p>)
    )
}
```