# Parse JSON from Firebase to object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, parsing

I exported the database from Firebase in Json format, and It looks weird but it's legit JSON syntax. Does anyone know how to parse this into a list of objects?

JSON code:

```json
{
  "users" : 
  {
    "GSIgfyiEGtZs5reYe4SpwFJVxDC2" :
    {
      "email" : "anic@hotmail.com",
      "password" : "Dava123",
      "score" : 0,
      "username" : "Anic2",
      "zdate" : "2-3"
    },
    "OHxA5ARnbYdsy9Ga1nxDy0gZQBv1" : {
      "email" : "dava@hotmail.com",
      "password" : "Dava123",
      "score" : 3,
      "username" : "dava",
      "zdate" : "01-03-2021  11:53"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `users` is not a JSON array, it's a JSON object with an arbitrary number of runtime property names with a fixed schema for the values.  Since you don't know the properties of the `users` object in advance, maybe see  [Javascript: Iterating over JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42352161/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the values, you can use the keys [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var myFireBaseObj = {
  "users" : 
  {
    "GSIgfyiEGtZs5reYe4SpwFJVxDC2" :
    {
      "email" : "anic@hotmail.com",
      "password" : "Dava123",
      "score" : 0,
      "username" : "Anic2",
      "zdate" : "2-3"
    },
    "OHxA5ARnbYdsy9Ga1nxDy0gZQBv1" : {
      "email" : "dava@hotmail.com",
      "password" : "Dava123",
      "score" : 3,
      "username" : "dava",
      "zdate" : "01-03-2021  11:53"
    }
  }
};

console.log( Object.keys(myFireBaseObj));

// if you want to get both values and keys / users etc seperately as objects
var keys = Object.keys(myFireBaseObj );
var values = Object.values(myFireBaseObj );

console.log(keys[0]);
// put your attribute you want here
console.log(values [0]['...']);
```

---

Option 2: if you want an array back, use `map` for e.g. adapt it below

```
 Object.keys(myFireBaseObj).map(function(a,i){
 // whatever you want in the array you map it here
 // you have to customize the nested levels
 return
 [i,myFireBaseObj[a].blahBlah.. ,
 myFireBaseObj[a].password] 
 })
```

---

**Update**: Added sample to show `for loop` to get the `key`, `values`

```
for (var key of Object.keys(myFireBaseObj)) {
    // this will give you the key & values for all properties
    console.log(key + " -> " + p[key])
    // .. process the data here! 
}
```

Comment: How can I access to second user's property password?

Comment: create a for loop.. I added a sample above.